# Binding energy of Hydrogen = 0 = 13.6 ${\rm eV}$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, hydrogen, binding-energy

I was solving nuclear physics today.I used the binding energy formula on hydrogen.I found that B=0.But,B is also,as mentioned in my textbook,13.6eV. How?

[image: The problem I was working on .Pls read it]

Answer (score 4):

The formula

$$B = (Z m_p + N m_n - M) c^2$$

is the *nuclear* binding energy. It's how much energy you need to give to a nucleus to split it apart into individual protons and neutrons. Since the hydrogen atom is a single proton, its binding energy is zero.

$13.6\ \mathrm{eV}$ is the binding energy of the hydrogen *atom*. It's how much energy you need to give it to split the proton and the electron. The formula for atomic binding energy is, analogously,

$$B_\text{atom} = (Z (m_p + m_e) + N m_n - M) c^2.$$

This formula is not very practical, though, because the total mass-energy is so much bigger than the binding energy. You would need to know the actual mass $M$ of the atom to something like 10 significant digits in order to do an accurate calculation.

Comment: Note that the best value for the proton's mass ([as of the 2018 CODATA analysis](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mpc2mev|search_for=proton+mass)) has an uncertainty of 0.29 eV. In fact we *do* know the proton mass well enough to measure the atomic binding energy directly. In principle. In practice, high-precision mass measurements use different techniques for charged versus neutral particles, which would introduce complicated systematic uncertainties into a direct measurement.